# Where is the best place to define frame sizes for subviews?

Tags: objective-c

Where do most programmers specify how big frames are supposed to be?  I tried to put the following code in the instance variables section of a .h file

```
    CGRect backButtonRect = CGRectMake(2 * w/25, 18 * h/25, 6 * w/25, 2 * h/25);
```

but it won't let me for some reason.  I want to put the parameters in a place that's easy to remember so I can debug it later.

Comment: It won't let you do it because you can't define an instance variable when you are declaring it.

Comment: What a bizarre language.

Comment: @eeeeeeeeee No, it's not bizarre, you just understand its design. You can move these into the `initWithXXX:` method or `#define BACK_BUTTON_RECT ((CGRect){ x, y, w, h })`.

Comment: Are you trying to define `backButtonRect` at file scope?  If not, what scope are you defining it in?  Where are `w` and `h` declared?

Comment: @Abizern I'll assume your question is rhetorical.  But I'm curious, did you mean a bad carpenter AND bad tools?  Or, did you simply mean bad carpenter or bad tools?  I've known good carpenters to do some pretty shoddy work with the inferior tools and materials available.  What are you eluding too exactly?  Maybe enlighten some of the readers and expand on your first comment in a manner that Wain has.  Thanks.

Comment: @robmayoff There. It's gone. Do you feel better now? (Yes - this is what I sound like when _I am_ being snarky).

Comment: @H2CO3 Thanks for your replies everyone!  What is the design goal of not being able to define an instance variable while you are declaring it?

Comment: The fact that you cannot initialize it where you declare is probably just because C did not allow it at the time that Objective-C was invented (and C still doesn't allow), and compilers and language runtimes were generally much simpler then so adding such a feature would have seemed like a big complication.

Comment: @robmayoff: In C, can't you write things like int a = 1?

Comment: You can write that, **if** `a` is a global, static, or local variable.  You cannot write that if `a` is an instance variable, a function argument, or a `struct` or `union` member.

Comment: @robmayoff: Wait C has instance variables?  I thought it didn't have classes?

Comment: Sorry, I was thinking Objective-C.  C does not have instance variables.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot initialize an instance variable in its declaration.  That's just the way Objective-C is.  It's different from Java or C# (or C++11) in this regard.  All instance variables are initialized to zero.

You didn't say what class contains this instance variable.

If you're loading the object from a XIB or storyboard, it doesn't matter what class it is; it will be initialized by receiving an `initWithCoder:` message.  So initialize `backButtonRect` in `initWithCoder:`.  Example:

```
- (instancetype)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aDecoder {
    if ((self = [super initWithCoder:aDecoder])) {
        CGFloat w = 100, h = 64;
        backButtonRect = CGRectMake(2 * w/25, 18 * h/25, 6 * w/25, 2 * h/25);
    }
    return self;
}
```

Alternatively, if you won't know `w` and `h` until all of your outlets are hooked up, initialize `backButtonRect` in `awakeFromNib`:

```
- (void)awakeFromNib {
    [super awakeFromNib];
    backButtonRect = CGRectMake(2 * w/25, 18 * h/25, 6 * w/25, 2 * h/25);
}
```

If you're creating the object in code, then it does matter what class it is.  If it's a `UIView` subclass, the designated initializer is `initWithFrame:`, so that's a good method to override for your initialization:

```
- (instancetype)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame {
    if ((self = [super initWithFrame:frame])) {
        CGFloat w = 100, h = 64;
        backButtonRect = CGRectMake(2 * w/25, 18 * h/25, 6 * w/25, 2 * h/25);
    }
    return self;
}
```

If it's a `UIViewController` subclass, then the designated initializer is `initWithNibName:bundle:`.

```
- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil {
    if (self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil]) {
        CGFloat w = 100, h = 64;
        backButtonRect = CGRectMake(2 * w/25, 18 * h/25, 6 * w/25, 2 * h/25);
    }
    return self;
}
```

Comment: Yep. A good job of explaining the tricky bit with initWithCoder.

Answer (score 0):

You should try not to have explicit frame definitions anywhere. If you do need them then putting them in an XIB with the view definitions is good. Where you do want to specify frames in code you should try to make things proportional and dynamic so the sizes of some things are set but most things are calculated based on the superview frame and the things with static sizes. This supports modifications in the future for slightly different screen sizes.

For the things you do need to specify, adding `#define` at the top of the .m file is good. It's good to name these with capitals and underscores so you can clearly see when reading the code that they are defined constants.